# How to align UIWebView video (from online DB) to center : Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, uiwebview, alignment

I am displaying a video to my `UIWebView` from an online Database as:

```
 //-------- Creating webview --------//
 UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 145, 300,190)];
 webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 webview.opaque = NO;
 [self.view addSubview:webview];

 //-------- Loading Video --------//
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.org/myProject/sample.php?name=123746"]];
 NSURL *nsurl=fileURL;
 [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

It is working great. But the video looks like below:

[image]

**So, Is there is any way to align the video to center of the web view?** Anyone please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I was not able to find any good inbuilt solution using Xcode, I have solved the issue with the help of `backend` and `HTML iframes`. I've saved the exact url in a data base and using HTML `<iframe>`, I loaded the video in the webview with   tag to the iframes.

Answer (score 1):

3 Options.

1. If the video will always be that size, make the `UIWebView` just slightly bigger and center that.
2. Use `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""]` to pass in javascript to adjust the css to center it.
3. If its a webpage you control, add css to the HTML to center the video div in the window

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. But the video size may vary, and I'm not loding from an html page, and it is not a web page. it is a video from online DB. And I am not familiar with JS. so can u describe the method '2' ?

Comment: @Thampuran well then I would suggest changing it to a html page as I don't know of any other way to achieve this

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do so? Here I'm loading the video from an online Database by calling a PHP page. So how can I make it to HTML?

Comment: @Thampuran so change it to a HTML page with an embedded video. Like how people embed a youtube video on their sites. Thats a completely other question based on how your backend / video is being setup. You'll need to research that

Comment: @Thampuran also on a side note I find it pretty hard to believe that their is no HTML in the webview above. Try printing out the contents, I'm sure their is a div tag somewhere, where you can centre the content

Comment: thanks for your support. I have managed to solve it in a different way. That I'll write here... :)